# What is the difference between "hello".length and "hello" .length?

Tags: ruby

I am surprised when I run the following examples in ruby console. They both produce the same output.

```
"hello".length
```

and

```
"hello"                     .length
```

How does the ruby console remove the space and provide the right output?

Answer (score 6):

You can put spaces wherever you want, the interpreter looks for the end of the line. For example:

Valid

```
"hello".
  length
```

Invalid

```
"hello"
  .length
```

The interpreter sees the dot at the end of the line and knows something has to follow it up. While in the second case it thinks the line is finished. The same goes for the amount of spaces in one line. Does it matter how the interpreter removes the spaces? What matters is that you know the behavior.

If you want you can even

```
"hello"   .      length
```

and it will still work.

I know this is not an answer to you question, but does the "how" matter?

EDIT: I was corrected in the comments below. The examples with multiple lines given above are both valid when run in a script instead of IRB. I was mixed them up with the operators. Where the following also applies when running a script:

Valid

```
result = true || false
```

Valid

```
result = true ||
  false
```

Invalid

```
result = true
  || false
```

Comment: Um, the `"hello"\n.length` one is perfectly valid. `irb` doesn't have quite the same parsing rules as Ruby itself does. Try it in a script of its own rather than in `irb` and you'll see.

Comment: You are correct. I mixed it up with the operators. `true || false` is valid, but `true \n || false` is not valid. While `true || \n false` is also valid. My bad.

Comment: What to do with the answer since half the answer is not valid. Delete it?

Comment: AFAIK the `.` handling w.r.t. newlines is a special case. You're free to edit your answer to correct/clarify things. No need to throw out a mostly-good answer over one little nit.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't have as much to do with the console as it has to do with how the language itself is parsed by the compiler.

Most languages are parsed in such a way that items to be parsed are first grouped into TOKENS. Then the compiler is defined to expect a certain SEQUENCE of tokens in order to interpret each programming statement.

Because the compiler is only looking for a TOKEN SEQUENCE, it doesn't matter if there is space in between or not.

In this case the compiler is looking for:

```
STRING DOT METHOD_NAME
```

So it won't matter if you write `"hello".length`, or even `"hello"  .  length`. The same sequence of tokens are present in both, and that is all that matters to the compiler.

If you are curious how these token sequences are defined in the Ruby source code, you can look at `parse.y` starting around line 1042:

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y#L1042

This is a file that is written using the [YACC language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc), which is a language used to define parsers with.

Even without knowing anything about YACC, you should already be able to get some clues on how it works by just looking around the file a bit.

Comment: Sometimes white space can introduce ambiguity, like `example(arg)` and `example (arg)` may be interpreted differently depending on context. It's generally best to avoid putting in unnecessary spaces.

Comment: Yes @tadman. Good point. This has to do with the compiler being unable to disambiguate (fancy word for "unable to read the programmer's mind") between two or more possible solutions to the programming statement.

Comment: This actually does have a bit to do with the console. `irb` interprets whitespace differently than Ruby itself does. Dumping `y = 'pancakes'\n.length` into `irb` will cause problems but that's perfectly fine in Ruby.

Comment: @muistooshort Ok you nitpickers ;) Can't get away with anything here today :-/ You win.